# When adding rows / columns dynamically in a table, how do you keep the container size?

Tags: html, css

```js
var rows = 55;
var cols = 140;
var rowsInput = document.getElementById("rowsId");
var colsInput = document.getElementById("colsId");
//initialize 2dim arrays 
var arr;// current generation array
var nextArr; // next generation array
function drawGrid() {
    let grid = document.getElementById("container");
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("class", "center");

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.setAttribute("id", i + "_" + j);
            cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
            tr.appendChild(cell);
            cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                if (cell.classList.contains("live")) {
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "dead");
                    arr[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else
                    cell.setAttribute("class", "live");
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            });
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    grid.appendChild(table);
}
function make2DArr() {
    arr = new Array(rows);
    nextArr = new Array(rows);
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Array(cols);
        nextArr[i] = new Array(cols);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
            nextArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
    var generateBtn = document.getElementById("generateBtnId");

 generateBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rows = rowsInput.value;
        cols = colsInput.value;
        remove();
        make2DArr();
        drawGrid();
    });
    
    function remove() {
    var tb = document.querySelector("table");
    tb.outerHTML = "";
}
function init() {
    make2DArr();
    drawGrid();
}
init();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(76, 77, 62, 0.514);
}
.center {

    margin: auto;
  width: 70rem;
  height: 30rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    border:1px rgb(26, 51, 192) solid;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;

}
table {
    border:1px rgb(241, 241, 241) solid;
    border-spacing: 0;
    flex:1;
}
.live {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.685);
}
.dead {
    background-color:rgba(228, 228, 241, 0.829);
}


td {
    flex:1;

    position: relative;
    border:1px rgb(29, 182, 29) solid;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
}

 button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button:hover {
      background-color: rgba(144, 180, 145, 0.596);
      color: rgb(54, 59, 54)
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="game.css">
    
</head>

<body>

<div class="center">
 <div id="container">
 </div>
 
  <button id="startBtnId"><span>Start</span></button>
  <button id="clearBtnId"><span>Clear</span></button>
  <button id="randomBtnId"><span>Random</span></button>
  <button id="generateBtnId"><span>Generate</span></button>
  <input type="text"  id="rowsId" value="rows">
  <input type="text"  id="colsId" value="cols">
  <select id="sizeId"> 
   <option value="Big">Big</option>
   <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
   <option value="Small">Small</option>
    </select>
  
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to enter a number of rows and columns manually and the new table will be contained in the fixed container size.
For example, when I weigh 20 rows and 20 columns the container will be the same size as the one where 50 lines and 50 columns are balanced.
Enter the number of rows and columns, and then click generate

Comment: Have you tried setting a width/height to the div in which you generate the table? Currently it only inherits those properties. You could also style the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified container as flex so if you add as many colum it will fit in to container, remove the flex and give width manual and check.

Comment: The container does remain at a fixed size but the table inside changes and a scroll arrow appears.